# Does any empty an array of a specific type holds object of that type or empty slots? (Garbage collector)

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In the following example which I am trying to understand. They say [(Core Java SCJP Quiz Questions (Google Play))](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.concretepage.javaquiz&hl=en) that **5** objects were created and **2** are for the Garbage collector.

When I tried to solve it. I came out with **3** objects and **1** for the garbage collector **(It is wrong I know)**. The three objects are:

1. `College [] c = new College[3]`;
2. `c[0] = new College();`
3. `College co = new College();`

---

- `co= null` is for the garbage collector.
- c[1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.concretepage.javaquiz&hl=en) is just a reference.

---

```
package example;

class Class {
    int [] cls = {1,2,3,4};
}

public class College{
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        College [] c = new College[3];
        c[0] = new College();
        
        College co = new College();
        c[1] = co;
        co= null;
        c[1] = null;
    }
}
```

---

### Questions

- What are the 5 created objects and 2 that are sent to GC.
- I don't get it. If we already created 3 objects in the array. then why did we instantiate `c[0] = new College();`
- I understood that `College [] c = new College[3]` is an array of type `College` that doesn't hold any object yet. Is that right or wrong?

---

I'll be sticking to an official java book from now on.

Comment: You are correct saying that when `c` is initialized, all the elements are `null`, meaning they don't contain any references. But who are `they`?

Comment: oh an app that contains a java quiz. they have multiple choices. @ Logan Kulinski

Comment: Yes, I too only see three objects created in the `College` class. Objects are garbage collected when they are no longer pointed to (in use).

Comment: @EJP sheesh So I am half right thank you lololol.  Why isn't  co sent to the garbage collector ?**co= null;**

Comment: `c[1]` is still using the object that `co` once referred to, even when you have `co = null;`

Comment: @LoganKulinski even when we make reference null? c[1] = null;

Comment: That statement then makes the reference unused.

Comment: @LoganKulinski It makes the reference `null`, just as the syntax suggests.

Comment: Yes, but I'm referring to the object that was initially created, not the reference held in `c[1]`.

Comment: thank you @LoganKulinski. I appreciate your help

Comment: @LoganKulinski Your exact words were 'makes the reference unused', which is meaningless. If you meant 'null ' you shouldn't have written 'reference'.

Comment: @EJP I said that in reference to his mention of the garbage collector, and how unused references will eventually be garbage collected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int [] cls = {1,2,3,4};
```

This creates one `int[]` object.

> What are the 5 created objects

Four objects are created [unless they're counting `String[] args`, which they probably shouldn't].

> and 2 that are sent to GC.

Nothing is 'sent to GC' by the code you posted, but when such code is in a method scope *everything* becomes eligible for GC when it exits, and the references that are nulled make the objects they previously referred to eligible for GC as well, if there are no other references to them.

> I don't get it. If we already created 3 objects in the array. then why did we instantiate c[0] = new College();

We didn't 'create 3 objects in the array'. We created an array with three empty slots.

> I understood that College [] c = new College[3] is an array of type College that doesn't hold any object yet. Is that right or wrong?

Correct.

Comment: I think my last question contradicts the one before it